# Change colormap of existed matplotlib Figure

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

Im wonder if there is functionality which helps me to change colormap of already existed figure (FigureCanvasTkAgg actually, which is basically inherite most of Figure methods and features)
I have little GUI which has Frame and FigureCanvasTkAgg object on it. And I want to change (using a button for example) color map of this figure. I create such butoon (RadioButton self.cmap) and callback :

```
def change_cmap(self):

    plt.set_cmap(self.cmap.get()) 
    self.canvas.draw () ## method (like show()) which draw figure
```

This works actually but when I deal with subplots as figure then this callback change cmap of last subplot ONLY. Any ideas how to deal with it? Why draw() method not update whole figure but only last subplot?

[image]

Process of subplots creating (need to be converted to O-O approach)

```
axes = [] # list of axes objects

fig,ax = plt.subplots ( figsize = (15,10) )

ax = fig.add_subplot ( 311 )
fig.axes[0].plot( offset[:max] , 'k' )
axes.append(ax)

ax = fig.add_subplot ( 312 )
fig.axes[1].plot ( cdp[:max] , 'b' )
axes.append(ax)

ax = plt.subplot ( 313 )
fig.axes[2].imshow( seg[: , :max] , aspect = 'auto' , cmap = cmap)
axes.append(ax)


for i in axes:
  i.set_cmap('seismic) ### This raise 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'set_cmap' error :(
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the pyplot functions `plt.xxxx()` which are acting on the *current* axes (see https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/tutorials/introductory/lifecycle.html for more details).

When you have several axes, you are strongly encouraged to use the object-oriented approach. Essentially you will have to loop through your suplots and call `im.set_cmap(...)` where im is a reference to the image returned by `imshow()`.

```
self.ims = []
#create subplots:
fig, axs = plt.subplots(3,1,figsize = (15,10))
axs[0].plot( offset[:max] , 'k' )
axs[1].plot ( cdp[:max] , 'b' )
im = axs[2].imshow( seg[: , :max] , aspect = 'auto' , cmap = cmap)
self.ims.append(im)

def change_cmap(self):
    for im in self.ims:
        im.set_cmap(self.cmap.get()) 
    self.canvas.draw () ## method (like show()) which draw figure
```

Comment: If I got you right, I have to call ax = plt.gca()  and then interate through this axes?

Comment: no, `plt.gca()` will always return the same subplot. You have to keep a list of axes when you created your subplots and iterate through that list. But I cannot help more without seeing the part of the code where you are creating the axes / subplots

Comment: I tried fig,ax = plt.subplots ( figsize = (15,10) ) but then it now allow me to iterate through ax ("'AxesSubplot' object is not iterable")

Comment: that code creates a single subplot. Your image clearly shows several subplots. Or several figures? Again, cannot help mroe without seeing some code.

Comment: I added some additional code where I create my subplots

Comment: `set_cmap()` is actually a property of the `AxesImage` returned by `imshow()` so you have to keep a reference to those as well if you want to change the colormaps. I've added some code that should help